# Blender mesh transparent in UE4

Tags: normals

Hi I'm having a problem with this mesh of mine. It's a relatively simple object, but it keeps appearing as transparent in UE4. I think it has something to do with normal but I'm not sure what exactly. I have already tried recalculating the normal and flipping the normals, but it just keeps appearing the same to no avail.

[image: Here is the mesh in Blender.]

[image: And here is how it appears in UE4.]

Comment: Game engines usually render only one side of the faces. Use the solidify modifier to add thickness to your mesh.

Comment: This worked. Thank you.